# incorporating a sys.argv into a mySQL query in python

Tags: python, mysql, string, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program that first queries with mySQL and then sorts that data. I want to be able to have a user type "python program_name.py mySQL_query" and have the program insert "mySQL_query" into the query at the beginning of the program. The issue I'm running into is the sys.argv command converts the input into a string, which mySQL then rejects. I've tried a few things to convert the sys.argv into a name instead of a string but they haven't been successful. Any ideas?

Comment: What does mySQL want from python?  In everything else I've used, mySQL *wanted* a string.

Comment: How can a MySQL query be anything but a string?  And what do you mean by "convert sys.argv into a name"?  Python has no thing called a name.
Perhaps if you included actual code with actual error messages?

Comment: The query is 
qb="SELECT DISTINCT q19_scan.array_orientation_equatorial, q19_scan.run_id, q19_scan.run_subid, q19_scan.patch_day_number, sys.argv[2] FROM q19_typeb NATURAL JOIN q19_scan NATURAL JOIN q19_timestream NATURAL JOIN q19_weather NATURAL JOIN q19_ces_usable WHERE "

and the error is
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sys.argv[2] FROM q19_typeb NATURAL JOIN q19_scan NATURAL JOIN q19_timestream NATURAL JOIN...' at line 1")

Comment: To improve the quality of the answers you get, you should provide new information to clarify your question by editing the question, Follow the "edit" link in the question post.  Don't elaborate on the question in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to like something like this:

```
qb="SELECT DISTINCT q19_scan.array_orientation_equatorial, q19_scan.run_id, q19_scan.run_subid, q19_scan.patch_day_number, %s FROM q19_typeb NATURAL JOIN q19_scan NATURAL JOIN q19_timestream NATURAL JOIN q19_weather NATURAL JOIN q19_ces_usable WHERE " % sys.argv[2]
```

I have replaced sys.argv[2] in your query with %s, and then applied formatting operator on this string with second operand being sys.argv[2]. You can read more about python's [formatting](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) operator in documentation, or even use newer formatting functions: